# Using traceur compiler with meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I would like to use Javascript generators on client code (and other ES6 features), but AFAIK it's not yet implemented in all major browsers yet or enabled by default. So I found [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler).

But I'm having trouble with Meteor integration. Traceur provides a command line compiler, which I could call as [meteor-typescript](https://github.com/grmlin/meteor-typescript) (even if it's not recommended), because I couldn't find documentation about compiling a string from Javascript with traceur.

Then, I guess a runtime dependency is also required and has to be served to the client. Can I use bower for that?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers.

**Edit:** I could call the compiler (see [my meteor-traceur](https://github.com/alepulver/meteor-traceur)), but I don't know how to add the runtime dependency. Traceur defines a RUNTIME_PATH, but I can't use it with api.add_files because the npm module isn't imported inside package.js (where Packages.on_use should be defined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The npm depencies are installed in the .npm directoy in the package. You can add the traceur runtime by adding this to package.js:

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.add_files(".npm/plugin/compileTraceur/node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur-runtime.js");
});
```

I forked your repository and fixed this: https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-traceur

I also created a demo app: https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-traceur-demo

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the delay. Now I believe wrapping NPM packages into Meteor doesn't make much sense when there isn't any Meteor-specific code. I'm currently considering [mimosa](http://mimosa.io/) as a JS preprocessor which also integrates browserify.

Comment: Meteor has its own build pipeline already. The Meteor specific code is integration the tool (e.g. Traceur) into the Meteor build pipeline. Yesterday, I released the first version of my es6-now package. It also allows you to use ES6 Modules with SystemJS. http://atmospherejs.com/package/es6-now

Comment: Great! Do you know by any chance about integration of "browserify" or another way to use NPM/Bower packages both in the server and the client?

Comment: You can use the Bower tool normally and create a smart package that adds the files to the client and server with api.add_files. I did this with Lodash for example. Or use an existing Meteor smart package. When you write own Meteor code, you can write it for client and server. Meteor makes this really easy. I personally don't have experience with Browserify.